# Hitman: Blood Money "you better watch out ..." Dropping bug

Tags: pc, hitman-blood-money

In the you better watch out mission when you drop any thing with the G key or even try to store weapons in cases, the game crashes. This makes it very hard to achieve a silent assassin rating. Is there any fix for this?
Edit: ok wikia says this bug only happens on cracked games soo it makes achievement of silent assassin impossible because you cant use the bomb to make an accident and cant use the sausage to render the dog  unconcious , because the dog actually is counted as a witness :|

Comment: Have you looked up what is causing the bug? I never had a bug causing issues with obtaining a Silent Assassin rating, though I did play some time ago, so it may be caused by newer patches.

Comment: Seems other people had this bug too, even when i put the bomb in th the studio it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently the only available solution to this is : to **BUY THE GAME!**

Ok, a long time has passed and despite the 10K views no one has answered this question so I assume every one else either was also looking for a solution to this or did not know of any solution. also no one commented to inform others that any given solution in the other answers actually worked for them.

So I answer this myself to the extent of my knowledge,
since that This problem Occurs on a pirated/cracked version and was an intentional bug to break the game for people who pirate the game, the only solution is to ACTUALLY BUY the Game, as I did after a couple of years, you can probably find it really cheap too.

Since about 2016 or 2017 I have not played any pirated games (could not do it before for a couple of reasons which were mostly out of my hands), just downloaded a dozen of repacks since then to use their data with my steam so I can cut down on the network traffic used by downloading my games.

---

So I sincerely hope others will be able to also switch to supporting the Devs by paying for the games.

Comment: won't mark any other answer even if it works as not to advertise or support pirating, but will up-vote if it really works.

Comment: also I'm not a hypocrite, I still understand there are people that might not be able to buy games legitimately due to many reasons which some might be acceptable by some, I just no longer do it, so I simply wait until I have the money to buy it.

Answer (score 2):

Use syringe to poison a sausage. At the point where you wanna throw/drop it, just take it in your hand, holster it and unholster it again like you would do a gun (by the Inventory button/key). The game counts it as dropped and the dog performs the eating and dying animation.
Happy gaming.

I found a workaround for this bug that has apparently been a nuisance to a lot of people after feeling nostalgic and playing Blood Money again. The way the "intentional" drop item function crashes the game I thought of non-intentional ways and thought up a few rather weird ones (such as when 47 drops something he's carrying when he wants to drag a body) but they won't end in Silent Assassin rating for obvious reasons. I tried clicking it at him while sneaking and a lot of other stuff. I finally came across this chance solution. It's been double checked and works. I assume whoever's got to this problem already knows everything else on how to get SA rating, so I'll skip the details.

Comment: Thanx i will try this firs thing in the morning and if it works i will mark your answer

Comment: @Hitman2847, did it work?

Comment: It actually did not work like you said, i holstered the poisoned saussage and equipped it again . the game considered this droping . but the dog ate the saussage and did not die . tried both syringes, both sedative and poison on saussage . nothing happens to the dog, @Timelord64 if you may try and post your answer here too we may come to a conclusion at least . did not work like described for me

Answer (score 1):

I got a Silent Assassin without drop. All u need to do is run towards your target & push him off the ledge using LMB(let the dog bark....nobody cares about a dog's opinion if there's no dead body around).

Comment: I Did That , and the Dog Still Counts as A witness !

Comment: No matter how you kill him it still counts the dog as a witness ,  even if you kill it afterwards. i have no idea how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the dog with a gun and still get the silent assassin ranking. Also, when you drag a body, you can stop the animation by taking the victim's pistol (if he/she has one) I tried these methods and was able to reach the SA ranking. Happy assasinations.